# cross database query on sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014, memory-optimized-tables

I have a database with a memory optimized table. I want to archive this table in another database. I want to write an stored procedure to do that.

I am implemented below sample from [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/cross-database-queries) and [2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584627(v=sql.120).aspx) successfully, but in these sample, the first database is not in memory and the second database is in memory.
In my case, the first database is  in memory and the second one can be in memory or not.

Here is my code:

1- my table :

```
USE [TestReport]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Report]    Script Date: 1/22/2018 4:40:04 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Report]
(
    [ReportID] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 NOT NULL,
    [Year] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DayOfYear] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductType] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationID] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 NOT NULL,
    [TotalSize] [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [TotalCount] [bigint] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    [LastReportTimeSpan] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 NULL,

INDEX [idx] NONCLUSTERED HASH 
(
    [ReportID],
    [DayOfYear]
)WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 131072),
CONSTRAINT [pk] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH 
(
    [ReportID],
    [Year],
    [DayOfYear],
    [ProductType],
    [ApplicationID]
)WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 131072)
)WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON , DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA )

GO
```

2- simple Stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ArchiveReport]
WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION, SCHEMABINDING, EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS BEGIN ATOMIC WITH
(
 TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL =  SNAPSHOT, LANGUAGE =  N'us_english'
)
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @currentdate DATETIME2;
         SET @currentdate = GETDATE();
        declare @maintainDay INT = 5

    INSERT  TestReportArchive.[dbo].Report
         SELECT [ReportID],
                [Year],
                [DayOfYear],
                [ProductType],
                [ApplicationID],
                [TotalSize],
                [TotalCount],
            [LastReportTimeSpan]
          FROM [dbo].[Report] 
         WHERE DATEADD(day, [DayOfYear] + @maintainDay, DATEADD(YEAR, [Year] - 1900, 0)) > @currentdate;

         DELETE FROM [dbo].[Report]
         WHERE DATEADD(day, [DayOfYear] + @maintainDay, DATEADD(YEAR, [Year] - 1900, 0)) > @currentdate;

     END;
END
```

3- simple stored procedure error

```
Msg 4512, Level 16, State 3, Procedure ArchiveReport, Line 12
Cannot schema bind procedure 'dbo.ArchiveReport' because name 'TestReportArchive.dbo.Report' is invalid for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format and an object cannot reference itself.

TestReportArchive is my destination database
```

4- using [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/cross-database-queries) and [2](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584627(v=sql.120).aspx). definition of table  variable

```
USE [TestReport]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedTableType [dbo].[MemoryType]    Script Date: 1/22/2018 4:35:14 PM ******/
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MemoryType] AS TABLE(
    [ReportID] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 NOT NULL,
    [Year] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DayOfYear] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductType] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationID] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 NOT NULL,
    [TotalSize] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [TotalCount] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [LastReportTimeSpan] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 NULL,
    INDEX [idx] NONCLUSTERED HASH 
(
    [ReportID],
    [DayOfYear]
)WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = 131072)
)
WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON )
GO
```

5- stored procedure with table variable

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ArchiveReport]
WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION, SCHEMABINDING, EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS BEGIN ATOMIC WITH
(
 TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL =  SNAPSHOT, LANGUAGE =  N'us_english'
)
     BEGIN
         DECLARE @currentdate DATETIME2;
         SET @currentdate = GETDATE();
        declare @maintainDay INT = 5

         DECLARE @InMem [dbo].[MemoryType];

        INSERT @InMem
        SELECT [ReportID],
                [Year],
                [DayOfYear],
                [ProductType],
                [ApplicationID],
                [TotalSize],
                [TotalCount],
            [LastReportTimeSpan]
         FROM [dbo].[Report] 
         WHERE DATEADD(day, [DayOfYear] + @maintainDay, DATEADD(YEAR, [Year] - 1900, 0)) > @currentdate;
         INSERT  TestReportArchive.[dbo].[Report]
         SELECT [ReportID],
                [Year],
                [DayOfYear],
                [ProductType],
                [ApplicationID],
                [TotalSize],
                [TotalCount],
            [LastReportTimeSpan]
         FROM @InMem

         DELETE FROM [dbo].[Report]
         WHERE DATEADD(day, [DayOfYear] + @maintainDay, DATEADD(YEAR, [Year] - 1900, 0)) > @currentdate;

     END;
END
```

6- Error from 5 stored procedure

```
Msg 4512, Level 16, State 3, Procedure ArchiveReport, Line 25
Cannot schema bind procedure 'dbo.ArchiveReport' because name 'TestReportArchive.dbo.Report' is invalid for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format and an object cannot reference itself.

TestReportArchive is my destination database
```

Comment: SCHEMABINDING
Binds the view to the schema of the underlying table or tables. When SCHEMABINDING is specified, the base table or tables cannot be modified in a way that would affect the view definition. The view definition itself must first be modified or dropped to remove dependencies on the table that is to be modified. When you use SCHEMABINDING, the select_statement must include the two-part names (schema.object) of tables, views, or user-defined functions that are referenced. **All referenced objects must be in the same database.**

Comment: [link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql)  [link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql)

Comment: thanks for your good answer jacob-h. i created simple stored procedure (not natively compiled procedures ) successfully. but another error occoured:   (0 row(s) affected)
Msg 41317, Level 16, State 6, Procedure ArchiveReport, Line 24
A user transaction that accesses memory optimized tables or natively compiled procedures cannot access more than one user database or databases model and msdb, and it cannot write to master.  my main problem is archive a in memory table with stored procedure.

Comment: Ultimately I created a non-memory-optimized table (ReportTemp) on the testReport (first Database) and change the stored procedure to insert data from Report Table to ReportTemp Table in the first database. Then I write another SP to move Data to archive Database. If anyone has a better solution ??

Comment: @afshar See my answer. Your two-step solution is the only supported solution.

Comment: @afshar Please resolve this question. If you have answered it yourself, please put an answer and accept it. This keeps the search functions on the site working properly for everyone. Your question still comes up as unanswered, even though you have answered it yourself in these comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I created a non-memory-optimized table (ReportTemp) on the testReport (first Database) and change the stored procedure to insert data from Report Table to ReportTemp Table in the first database. Then I write another SP to move Data to archive Database.

Answer (score 2):

Cross-database queries involving Memory-Optimized Tables are not supported.

[Unsupported SQL Server Features for In-Memory OLTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/unsupported-sql-server-features-for-in-memory-oltp)

> A query cannot access other databases if the query uses either a
>   memory-optimized table or a natively compiled stored procedure. This
>   restriction applies to transactions as well as to queries.